# Group mongodb collection and output the result as a single object

Tags: mongodb-query, lodash, node-mongodb-native

Is there a way to group a collection which looks like

```
[
  {_id: "5bd258a7877e74059b6b65b2", year: 2017, title: "One"},
  {_id: "5bd258a7877e74059b6b65b3", year: 2017, title: "Two"},
  {_id: "5bd258a7877e74059b6b65b4", year: 2018, title: "Three"},
  {_id: "5bd258a7877e74059b6b65b5", year: 2018, title: "Four"}
]
```

and output the result as

```
{
  2017: [
    0: {_id: "5bd258a7877e74059b6b65b2", title: "One", …}
    1: {_id: "5bd258a7877e74059b6b65b3", title: "Two", …}
  ],
  2018: [
    0: {_id: "5bd258a7877e74059b6b65b4", title: "Three", …}
    1: {_id: "5bd258a7877e74059b6b65b5", title: "Four", …}
  ]
}
```

using mongodb aggregations? Similar to how lodash [`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy) works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with the following mongoDB aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
      _id: "$year",
      docs: {
        $addToSet: "$$CURRENT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "data": {
        "$push": {
          "k": {
            $toString: "$_id"
          },
          "v": "$docs"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can see the [result here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LAokMbsysp5)

The idea is to group the data in a way where we can utilize [**`$arrayToObject`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/). First group gives you the grouped by year where the second is just prep for `$arrayToObject` which requires `key,  value` object. Last thing is the [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html).

This requires **MongoDB 3.6** and up due to `$arrayToObject` being introduced in that version. Before that you had to use `$push` etc.